# .NET Core Controller API call to Azure SQL Database works in localhost but not in deployed Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-core, react-router, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

## Summary:

I have a .NET Core project that uses the React web app template for the front end. This app uses Entity Framework Core to connect to an Azure SQL Database. I used the Db-Scaffold command to generate my models (just one table at the moment), and created a controller to return this table. Locally, this works fine and the table (JSON) is returned at localhost/api/Users. However when I deploy the website to Azure (CD pipeline is VS 2017 - > GitHub -> DockerHub -> Azure Web App), navigating to **mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/Users** just renders the login page (React) of my app.

## Attempts:

I have tried:

- Adding a connection string as a shared value in Azure (named DefaultConnection)
- Adding all the outbound IP's of the Azure Web App to the Azure SQL Whitelist
- Running the following in the consoles of the web app

  ```
  fetch('api/users')
  ```

  This just returns:

  ```
  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
  ```
- I have also tried changing database values and refreshing the local version to make sure it was not just a cached page and sure enough the changes were reflected locally.
- I also set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the Web App settings in Azure to Production. Although when I go to the error message, page (through the console) I get this:

  ```
     <h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
       <h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

  <p>
  <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>0HLK3RLI8HD9Q:00000001</code>
  </p>

  <h3>Development Mode</h3>
    <p>
    Swapping to the <strong>Development</strong> environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.
   </p>
   <p>
      <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
         It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
           For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>
    and restarting the app.
      </p>
  ```

## Code

**UsersController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{

    private readonly AccrubalanceDbContext _context;
    public UsersController(AccrubalanceDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Users>> Get()
    {
        return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
     {
       "ConnectionStrings":  {
          "DefaultConnection":<MyConnectionStringGoesHere>     
     },
```

**index.js** (just in case React might be the routing problem)

```
   const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')                                             
   [0].getAttribute('href');
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

      ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>,
        rootElement);

       registerServiceWorker();
```

**Startup.cs** (could be potentially problem with HTTP routing in Prod?)

```
       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AccrubalanceDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

## Conclusion

In conclusion, I need this API call to work within the hosted Azure Web App like it does on my local machine.  I know I am close since I got it to work locally, but I am missing something along the way to Azure. Any help or pointers you can provide would be great :)

<sup>I am still new to SO and took my time to do my best to format this correctly. I am open to constructive formatting critiques and suggestions to help me improve.</sup>

## Edit:

As I mentioned before, I am using docker for CD/CI. So I ran my docker container locally and the api does not work there either. Docker throws this warning in the command window when I navigate to the apps home page.

```
      warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
       Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

---

### Edit 1 Determination

I also found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108658/how-to-make-net-core-mvc-api-react-react-router-work-together) which points to react routing being an issue. I have looked in Kudo in my Azure app and I do not have a web.config. Could potentially try adding on but I do not have the regular Windows UI since my app is a Linux server.

**The container build acts like the Azure App does, may not be an Azure issue. Still unsure why docker is acting differently than running in VS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

There is obviously some problem with Docker. Since it was becoming more of a headache then a help, I removed it from the deployment pipeline and just followed the [instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet). Once I did this deployment method, all the API's worked. Only downside is I had to make a new app in Azure.